# Connecting to S3 on localhost WAMP

Tags: assets

I've managed to connect to the S3 bucket on my live server, but when pressing "Refresh" on my WAMP running on localhost that list doesn't populate / is blank.

There isn't an error message as far as I can tell. Is there a way that I can debug why this is happening?

Edit: to clarify, this is for Assets 2.

Cheers, Andrew

Comment: Hey Andie - I'm curious if you can do anything that involves outgoing operations, such as pinging another site, or doing the 'new version check' with EE rom your WAMP install? I suspect that it's limiting outbound requests somewhere in your WAMP config.

Comment: Yes, the new version check and pinging both work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was revolved by installing CURL on the WAMP machine. It's a bit odd that "New Version Check" worked without CURL, but perhaps that uses a different method or I misunderstood.

I enabled CURL in WAMP by going to WAMP > PHP > Extensions and enabling the CURL extension.

Comment: Thank you for the update, Andie!  I am glad you got it working. :)

Comment: Hey Andie, thanks for posting this back here for everyone to benefit. You should accept your own answer in this case. :)